# Hibernate list of custom composite type

Tags: hibernate

Joda Time has no concept of an interval between LocalTimes, so I made one:

```
public final class LocalInterval
{
  private LocalTime start;
  private LocalTime end;
  ..
```

Of course I made Hibernate support, too, storing the local time as two properties, "start" and "end":

```
public class PersistentLocalIntervalAsTime implements CompositeUserType, Serializable
{
  public String[] getPropertyNames() {return new String[]{"start", "end"};}
  ...
```

In my package-info.java class, I mapped "LocalInterval":

```
@TypeDef(
  name = "LocalInterval",
  typeClass = PersistentLocalIntervalAsTime.class
),
```

So now I just want to have a list of LocalInterval inside MyClass:

```
@CollectionOfElements(targetElement=LocalInterval.class)
List<LocalInterval> intervals;
```

Hibernate doesn't like that, and says it can't figure out the type. So I tried:

```
@CollectionOfElements(targetElement=LocalInterval.class)
@Type(type="LocalInterval")
List<LocalInterval> intervals;
```

That at least generated a schema, but the schema has:

```
create table myclass_intervals (
  element time,
  myclass varchar(40) not null
) ENGINE=InnoDb;
```

That doesn't look right---shouldn't I have two TIME columns, "start" and "end", instead of one TIME column "element"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have to explicitly indicate to Hibernate that multiple columns should be used:

```
@CollectionOfElements(targetElement=LocalInterval.class)
@Type(type="LocalInterval")
@Columns(columns={@Column(name="start"), @Column(name="end")})
List<LocalInterval> intervals;
```

I don't know why Hibernate doesn't figure this out automatically by querying PersistentLocalIntervalAsTime---or at least throw an error instead of creating a default single column.